How to pass data from Excel to R running in VBA
I'm running R in a Shell in VBA. The VBA saves the file with ActiveWorkbook.Save and then the R script that runs in the shell includes openxlsx::read.xlsx() to read in data from the active workbook. However, this takes a while to run and I'm wondering if there is a faster way to pass data tables to the R script running in the shell.
Sub RunRScript(Rpath As String, _
                scriptPath As String, _
                parameters As String)
    Dim command As String
    Dim shell As Object
 
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
   
    ' Combine and quote paths
    command = Chr(34) & Rpath & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) & scriptPath & Chr(34) & " " & parameters
    MsgBox command
    ' Debugging: Print command to Immediate window
    Debug.Print command
    ' Create WScript.Shell object
    Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    ' Execute the command
    shell.Run command, 1, True ' 1 = normal window, False = do not wait for completion
 
    'MsgBox "R script complete..."
End Sub


What is "a while" roughly, and how much data are you processing?

It could take a minute just to save the Excel file, because it's on a network drive. The data is about 100,000 rows and 35 columns

You can't save a copy to a faster local drive?

That's an option, but I was hoping there would be a more clever solution. The BERT Excel add-in was able to pass data back and forth seamlessly; what was the trick there?
